# PARSEC:ferret : What is the sketch size in ferret code

Tags: c, linux, performance, ubuntu, benchmarking

I'm taking a look the ferret code, I found that **the quality or speed of ferret-engine can be changed as the sketch size varies** in some papers. 
But, I could't find the variable of sketch-size the paper/manual mentioned.
(the manual I refer is by Princeton univ)

I guess that 'sketch size' seems to be value 'IMAGE_DIM' in image/extract.c

```
#include <math.h>
#include "image.h"

#define MAXR    256

#define IMAGE_DIM       14

static float   dw[IMAGE_DIM] =  {6.0, 3.0, 1.5, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.04, 0.007, 0.007};
```

But, when I changed this value and array contents, it said error

Is there anyone who treats ferret of PARSEC?